# Built-in Sound Recorder app | Nokia G50

Tags: android-13, nokia

I have Nokia G50, running Android 13
I can not find any built-in sound recorder app. I am not referring to call recording app but one that can record audio that doesn't originate from the device.
Does anyone have an idea of such app comes with this model?
Is it an app that is provided by the OS or the device manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

There is a related article on [Nokia Support - How can I record a voice clip on my Nokia smartphone?](https://www.nokia.com/phones/en_us/support/topics/media-and-other-features/how-can-i-record-a-voice-clip-on-my-nokia-smartphone)

> You can use the pre-installed Keep app to record a voice clip. Alternatively, you can search for third-party apps in the Play Store.

Nokia relies on Google Keep for voice recording, but it doesn't have an independent sound recorder app.

While the [AOSP](https://source.android.com/) has [SoundRecorder](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_soundrecorder) app, the manufacturer can and do customize their Android ROMs, including removing AOSP apps.